# MYSQL - Verificar se a PK existe se sim faz UPDATE se não existir faz INSERT

Tags: mysql

Eu não queria ter que faz duas transações no banco de dados, atualmente venho fazendo `SELECT` primeiro para saber se o registro já existe na tabela, depois eu faço ou `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` dependendo do caso, gostaria de fazer apesar uma transação é possível? algo tipo `INSERT .... IF NOT EXISTS THEN UPDATE ...` ?

Comment: Está usando algum framework? qual linguagem? No laravel tem um método chamado CreateOrUpdate, verifica se tem o registro e se não tiver de acordo com a condição ele cria.

Comment: Ou pode criar um [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar o `ON DUPLICATE KEY`:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="A", age=19
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55dbb4/1)**, com `ON DUPLICATE KEY` e `REPLACE`.

---

#### Referências

[13.2.6.2 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

[Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: exatamente o que eu procurava, apesar de achar estranho o log me mostrar 2 row(s) affected quando já existe o registro, acho que o MySql é quem fica com o serviço p/ mim ta valendo, obrigado!

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Acho que essa questão do log mostrar "2 row(s)" daria uma nova ótima pergunta técnica para os grandes conhecedores! rs

Answer (score 5):

Pode ser interessante o `REPLACE INTO`

Funciona como o INSERT só que quando encontra um PK ou UniqueKey, a linha antiga é removida e então a nova é inserida.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Exemplo de uso:

```
REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'New', '2014-08-20 18:47:42');
```

## Particionamento e bloqueio (partitioning and locking)

O `REPLACE INTO` bloqueia apenas as partições com linhas a serem inseridas ou substituídas. No entanto, se um valor AUTO_INCREMENT for gerado para qualquer coluna de particionamento, todas as partições serão bloqueadas.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-locking.html

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55dbb4/1) com os 2 exemplos.

Comment: achei Interessante também